# I need helt at "sudo pip3 install email"

Tags: email, pip, installation, sudo

I import in Python 3.5

"smtplib" and got the message "No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' ist not a package.

when I try to install 'email'  I get the message no module named 'CStringIO'

Answer (score 0):

> 'email' ist not a package.

I suspect your script is named `email.py` and thus it shadows built-in `email` package.

Rename your `email.py` to something that doesn't collide with names from the stdlib. Certainly not to `test.py`.

Comment: Hallo phd DANKE. (hätte auch selbst fiden müssen) ! Danke für Deine Unterstützung